# How to use Rule:unique with array of values compared to another column in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

i have a request for array of values and i validate it with the following code

```
$request->validate([
  'doctor_id.*'     => ['required'],
  'doctor_id'     => [Rule::unique('project_orders')->where(function ($query) use ($student) {
    $query->where('student_id', $student->id);
  })],
]);
```

but the unique validation doesn't work and the data was inserted to the table with duplication

i want the doctor_id field to be unique with the student_id column, what should be the correct rule?

any help please ?

Comment: "i want the doctor_id filed to be unique with the student_id column" can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: i want doctor_id not to duplicated with the same student_id

Comment: So `doctor_id` and `student_id` are both columns in the `project_orders` table, and you only want each student or doctor to have a single order?

Comment: yes, that's i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to do validation on database level, so you will add in your migration

```
$table->unique(['doctor_id', 'student_id']);
```

This will make sure that there will be no duplication for same `doctor_id` and `student_id` values

Then in your validation layer you will add

```
$request->validate([
  'doctor_id.*' => 'unique:project_orders,doctor_id,NULL,id,student_id,'.$student->id,
]);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224514/discussion-on-answer-by-mmabdelgawad-how-to-use-ruleunique-with-array-of-values).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the validation like this

```
$request->validate([
    'doctor_id.*' => [ Rule::unique('project_orders', 'doctor_id')->where('student_id', $student->id) ]
]);
```

Comment: Hm... thats strange. May be its because of the quotes (apokryfos’ edit) I was sure it would work.

Comment: this is worked with me `$request->validate(['doctor_id.*' => ['required','unique:project_orders,doctor_id,NULL,id,student_id,'.$student->id, 'distinct']]);`